# Apply SummarizeGrowth on a grouped dataframe using group_by

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, grouping

I am trying to apply the function growthcurver::SummarizeGrowth after grouping a dataframe (df) using group_by. The data continues like that until Time=96. This is just a sample to show how the df looks like:

| Time | Bacteria | Isolate | Experiment | log10_OD600 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | A1 | January | -1 |
| 0 | B | A1 | January | -1 |
| 0 | C | A1 | January | -1 |
| 0 | A | A1 | February | -0,95 |
| 0 | B | A1 | February | -0,98 |
| 0 | C | A1 | February | -0,88 |
| 1 | A | A1 | January | -0,86 |
| 1 | B | A1 | January | -0,88 |
| 1 | C | A1 | January | -0,85 |
| 2 | A | A1 | January | -0,80 |
| 2 | B | A1 | January | -0,77 |
| 2 | C | A1 | January | -0,65 |

So far, I have tried the next code:

```
parameters <- df %>%
           group_by(Bacteria, Isolate, Experiment) %>%
           group_modify(~
                growthcurver::SummarizeGrowth(
                  data_t = .x$Time, 
                  data_n = .x$log10_OD600, 
                  blank = NA))
```

I also have tried the next one:

```
f <- function(log10_OD600) SummarizeGrowth(df$Time, df$log10_OD600)

parameters<- df %>%
          group_by(Bacteria, Isolate, Experiment) %>%
          do(lapply(., f))
```

I am aiming to get a dataframe, or a list, with the logistic model parameters , something like that:

| Bacteria | Isolate | Experiment | n0 | r | t_mid | t_gen | auc_l | auc_e |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A1 | January | 0.33 | 1.8e-05 | 1.11 | 8.77 | 0.61 | 5.11 |
| B | A1 | January | 0.35 | 1.8e-04 | 1.00 | 8.43 | 0.45 | 5.67 |
| C | A1 | January | 0.25 | 1.6e-05 | 1.30 | 4.43 | 0.65 | 5.00 |

Comment: Did  you meant the log column to be numeric or character (as there is `,` inplace of `.`)

Comment: I want the log_OD600 column to be used as numeric. Inmy dataframe this column is marked as numeric.
```
class(df$log10_OD600)
[1] "numeric"
´´´

Comment: With the example showed, I get only 0 as values from the `growthcurver`.  May be it is related to the data showed

Comment: It's because I only included a sample of the data, the data continues until Time= 96. In my example, I only showed the first hour. It was just to illustrate the different variables that I wanted to group using group_by. But your code worked smoothly. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could extract the 'vals' from the `list` output and select those specific elements

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>%
     group_by(Bacteria, Isolate, Experiment) %>% 
     group_modify(~ growthcurver::SummarizeGrowth(
                  data_t = .x$Time, 
                  data_n = .x$log10_OD600, 
                  blank = NA) %>% 
          pluck("vals") %>% 
          {.[c("n0", "r", "t_mid", "t_gen", "auc_l", "auc_e")]} %>% 
      as.data.frame, .keep = TRUE )  %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 9
  Bacteria Isolate Experiment    n0     r t_mid t_gen auc_l auc_e
  <chr>    <chr>   <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A        A1      February       0     0     0     0     0     0
2 A        A1      January        0     0     0     0     0     0
3 B        A1      February       0     0     0     0     0     0
4 B        A1      January        0     0     0     0     0     0
5 C        A1      February       0     0     0     0     0     0
6 C        A1      January        0     0     0     0     0     0
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Time = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), Bacteria = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", 
"C", "A", "B", "C"), Isolate = c("A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", 
"A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1"), Experiment = c("January", 
"January", "January", "February", "February", "February", "January", 
"January", "January", "January", "January", "January"), log10_OD600 = c(-1, 
-1, -1, -0.95, -0.98, -0.88, -0.86, -0.88, -0.85, -0.8, -0.77, 
-0.65)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```